# Matlab plotting the sum of a dataset

Tags: matlab, sum, matlab-figure

for my code I have a 375x223x91 dataset (called 'data1') and I am having difficulty plotting this as a figure. I can successfully plot individual slices using:

```
figure
imagesc(data1(:,:,50))
axis image 
impixelinfo
colormap(jet)

% top-down view of slice 50 (of the 91 slices) of 'data1'.
```

However I would like to sum each of the 91 slices and plot the top-down view. I have tried to write a 'for loop' and sum all 91 slices in the z-direction then plot this but I get errors. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

(extra guidance adding a 3D image will also be appreciated)

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: Error using image
Indexed CData must be size [MxN], TrueColor CData must be
size [MxNx3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

Error in imagesc (line 18)
    hh = image(varargin{1},'CDataMapping','scaled');

Comment: Try using `squeeze` on the results before plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum your data along the third dimension you should use the dimension input to `sum`:

```
sdata = sum(data1, 3);
```

Then you can display it normally.

```
imagesc(sdata);
```

As far as plotting 3D images, using `pcolor` is one way that you could do this.

```
p = pcolor(sdata);
set(p, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
```

This will place the image at `z = 0`. You can alter the `ZData` if you want to change it's position.

```
zvalue = 10;
set(p, 'ZData', 0 * get(p, 'ZData') + zvalue);
```

The other option is to use a `surf` object with the `FaceColor` set to `texturemap` and the `CData` set to your image data.

```
s = surf(ones(2));
set(s, 'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', sdata);
```

You can adjust the `XData`, `YData`, and `ZData` of the surface to adjust the position in 3D space.